# Clear NGRX State From Stores

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a feature reducers in my application:-

```
fromCompnay = {
  list:listReducer,
  growth:growthReducer
}

fromEmployee = {
  list:listReducer,
  growth:growthReducer
}

StoreModule.forFeature('company',fromCompany);
StoreModule.forFeature('employee',fromEmployee);
```

Is their a clean way to reset the state for these reducers.

Answer (score 2):

Probably via a meta-reducer, see below

[image]

Comment: I agree, resetting reducer somehow looks a bit crude, but setting the state to undefined is the most efficient way.